# JAVA - Regex Issue

Tags: java, regex

Just testing out some special regex characters and just came across some behaviour I could not explain. An un escaped full-stop stands for any character, therefore (for example) matching `3` to `"."` returns `true`, however, when I match `3` to `"[.]"`, it returns `false`. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most other metacharacters, `.` loses its special meaning in a character class (the `[]`).  There, it just means "a dot".

Answer (score 1):

Inside the squares "." means full-stop and not any char.

So the regex "[.]" match "." and not "3".